# console log event object shows different object properties than it should have

Tags: javascript, dom-events

With below code I noticed that in the browser console when I log the event, the value for `currentTarget` logs null. However when I log `e.currentTarget` it logs a value. Any idea's on how that works?

```
var button = document.getElementById("btn");

var eventButtonHandler = function(e) {
  var button = e.target;
  console.log(e); // logs MouseEvent object with currentTarget:null
  console.log(e.currentTarget); // logs a value
  if(!button.classList.contains("active"))
    button.classList.add("active");
  else
    button.classList.remove("active");
};

button.addEventListener("click", eventButtonHandler);
```

A jsbin can be found here: http://jsbin.com/xatixa/2/watch?html,js,output

Comment: I suspect it's related to the fact that the objects logged in the console are "live", they're linked to the actual object in memory. So while the handler is running, the target is non-null, but the property changes to null later on, and that's what you see when you expand the object in the console.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37130320/console-logging-object-shows-2-different-values

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is an artifact of the way the Javascript console works when you log an object. The log doesn't contain a copy of all the object properties, it just contains a reference to the object. When you click on the disclosure triangle, it then looks up all the properties and displays them.

In this case, at the time you call `console.log(e)`, there's a DOM element in the `currentTarget` property. But sometime later, that property is reset to `null` for some reason. When you expand the `event` object, that's what you see.

A simple example that demonstrates this is:

```js
var foo = { };
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    foo['longprefix' + i] = i;
}
console.log(foo);
foo.longprefix90 = 'abc';
```

When you view the object in the console, you'll see that `foo.longprefix90` contains `"abc"`, even though it contained `90` at the time that `console.log(foo)` was called.

The demonstration needs to use an object with lots of properties. When it's logging, it shows the first few properties that fit in the console, so those are in the early snapshot. Only properties after that display this anomalous behavior.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. Tnx.

Comment: I also encounter this issue just now, with the help of jQuery, i can log the value instead of reference : console.log($.extend({}, e))