# Console logging object shows 2 different values

Tags: angularjs, date, object

[image: What the...]

This is insane, or is it?! If I access departuredate directly I get the correct value of 2016-05-18.

```
console.log(searchFactory.search.searchparams.journeys[0].departuredate); // 2016-05-18 
console.log(searchFactory.search.searchparams.journeys[0] //stored in the object as 2010-05-10
```

However if I console.log() the entire object as in the attached screenshot, it is reset to todays date. How is that even possible? Ultimately the value is assigned to my Factory, which ends up being 2016-05-10 - today. Somewhere along the line the date is getting changed to todays date and for the life of me I don't understand how.

```
$scope.$watch('date', function(newDate) {
    searchFactory.search.searchparams.journeys[0].departuredate = moment(newDate.startDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    searchFactory.search.searchparams.journeys[0].returndate = moment(newDate.endDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    console.log(searchFactory.search.searchparams.journeys[0]);    
});
```

I am going insane, trying to figure this out.

Essentially I am watching the date scope item, which all workds fine. The newDate then gets assigned to my factory for storage and later use. As you can see I am simply logging the object to see the value. You can see in the screenshot how it carries two different values... which to my believe was impossible until now.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to share more of your code for anybody to figure this out.

Comment: @thepio there is not much else going on. I have wrapped the code in the $watch function. Bottom line is I am ending up with 2 different values, based on how I access it in the console.

Comment: I understand what you explained. But this seems to be such a weird problem that could take a lot of effort to solve. Hopefully someone can help you, I think I can't :/

Comment: What do you mean by "If I access departuredate directly"?

Comment: console.log(searchFactory.search.searchparams.journeys[0].departuredate) @1.618

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is(was) a [known bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35801) in webkit that still has yet to hit chrome 4 years later.

> As of today, dumping an object (array) into console will result in objects' properties being
>   read upon console object expansion (i.e. lazily). This means that dumping the same object while
>   mutating it will be hard to debug using the console.
>
> This change starts generating abbreviated previews for objects / arrays at the moment of their
>   logging and passes this information along into the front-end. This only happens when the front-end
>   is already opened, it only works for console.log(), not live console interaction.

Seen [here](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/125174).

[You can use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) `obj.toString()` in the meantime to log as you intend.

Comment: Bizarre, doesn't solve my underlying issue, but at least I am not crazier than I thought. Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't obj.toString() solve your problem? It will print the state of the object at the time of the log.

Comment: The date somehow reverts to today's date after it is applied to the factory. Logging seemed to show the madness that caused that, but if that is a chrome bug then back to square one. It's still a very bizarre issue. I believe it is has something to do with the movement library at this stage.

Comment: My money is on a coding error. Make sure newDate is what you think it is. It might be moment's default to set it to today's date if something is invalid.

Comment: That was my initial guess, which lead me to the logging of everything. The correct date comes through, but on the state change, reverts. At least I can move further down the code now, knowing the issue isn;t in the $watch function. Thanks again, mate.