# Matter JS - event.pairs array is blank on collision

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I'm using [MatterJS](http://brm.io/matter-js) to animate some objects on a canvas. At one point in the animation there is a collision between two of my objects. I'm successfully detecting the event with the below code:

```
Events.on(engine, 'collisionStart', function(event) {

    console.log(event)

});
```

What i'm trying to identify is which two objects are colliding. When I console.log event.pairs I get an empty array. I would have thought it would have returned an array of the two objects that are colliding. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Likely a dupe of [console log event object shows different object properties than it should have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496176/console-log-event-object-shows-different-object-properties-than-it-should-have)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You Really have no errors. you must see your pair on position zero, the library matterjs have a problem printing this value from event main. you must deploy your response and you will able to see your pairs, so:

```
Events.on(engine, 'collisionStart', function(event) {
     console.log("Evento: ", event)
     var pairs = event.pairs;
     console.log("Pair no visible: ", pairs)
     console.log("Pair visible: ", pairs[0]);
     console.log("colision between " + pairs[0].bodyA.label + " - " + pairs[0].bodyB.label);
});
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/cvalencia/pen/OjYdvE), i am showing a simple example.

Comment: It's not a problem with MJS, it's a "problem" (characteristic, really) with browsers. They often print live objects which can go stale once the event is invalidated.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing answer of Cristian Agudelo, you need to copy state of pairs and then do what you want:

```
Matter.Events.on(engine, "collisionStart", function(e)
{
    var pairs = e.pairs.slice(); // copy
    ...
}
```

Comment: You don't need to copy them unless you're logging them. The problem isn't the code, it's the log view into the object going stale over time. The issue here is that the extra slice can slow things down when it's not really necessary for logic.

Answer (score 1):

in order to successfully work with collisions in Matter js, try to access each pair of the returned array from the event object.

```js
Events.on(engine, 'collisionStart', (event) => {
  event.pairs.forEach((collision) => {
    console.log(collision);
  });
});
```

[image]