# Mouse event currentTarget overwrite + Rxjs issue

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Currently I'm using Rxjs and it seems the original event might have been partially discarded at the time I process it. CurrentTarget is gone.

```js
const canvasMousedown$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(chart, 'mousedown');
const canvasMousemove$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(chart, 'mousemove');
const canvasMouseup$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(chart, 'mouseup');

const canvasSelection$ = canvasMousedown$.concatMap((startEvent) => {
  return canvasMousemove$.takeUntil(canvasMouseup$).map((endEvent) => [startEvent, endEvent])
});

canvasSelection$.subscribe((events) => {
  // currentTarget is gone
  // I need to past the events some third party function
  // which depends on the currenTarget 
   console.log(events);
});
```

My first question can I somehow avoid this discard?

My workaround would be just simple overwrite the currentTarget with the original:

event.currentTarget = somethingEl

but I use typescript and the event is a const:
"Cannot assign to 'currentTarget' because it is a constant or a read-only property"

My second question can I somehow overwrite or clone the event to contain the new currentTarget?

Thank you!

Comment: Interesting, it appears to be set to `null` to save memory?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496176/when-loggin-an-event-object-currenttarget-is-null-but-when-logging-event-curre

Answer (score 0):

Create a copy of the event object to bypass the browser setting `currentTarget` null after the event.

```
const canvasMousedown$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(chart, 'mousedown')
    .map(e => ({ currentTarget: e.currentTarget }))
const canvasMousemove$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(chart, 'mousemove')
    .map(e => ({ currentTarget: e.currentTarget }))
const canvasMouseup$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(chart, 'mouseup')
    .map(e => ({ currentTarget: e.currentTarget }))

const canvasSelection$ = canvasMousedown$.concatMap((startEvent) => {
  return canvasMousemove$.takeUntil(canvasMouseup$).map((endEvent) => [startEvent, endEvent])
});

canvasSelection$.subscribe(events => {
    console.log(events)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Yes as I mentioned that what I want to achieve but I cant clone and rewrite an event properly.

my problem:
I need to call a third function which is need a MouseEvent (so I need the whole event). 
Plus I need to put back somehow the currentTarget for the third party.

I dont need to save the currentTarget beacuse I know it what is it (the chart element). And your solution If I see correctly just dropping the event and make a new object with the currentTarget.

Comment: Read about "deep cloning". [jQuery extend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) does what you want. `.map(e => $.extend({}, e))`