# Vue Composition Api .value returns null

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-composition-api

I have a "composable" axios function like this

```html
export const useFetch = (url: string, config: any = {}) => {
  const data = ref(null)
  const status = ref()
  const error = ref(null)
  const loading = ref(false)
  const fetch = async () => {
    loading.value = true
    error.value = null
    try {
      const result = await service.request({
        url,
        ...config
      })
      status.value = result.status
      data.value = result.data
    } catch (ex) {
      error.value = ex
    } finally {
      loading.value = false
    }
  }
  fetch()
  return { status, error, data, loading }
}
```

In a separate file like user.vue, I call useFetch like this

```html
  setup() {
    const { data, error } = useFetch(
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/po3sts/1',
      {
        method: 'get'
      }
    )
    console.error(error)
    console.error(error.value)
    return { data, error }
  }
```

My problem is when I console.error(error), I can clearly see

```html
Object { value: Getter & Setter }
value: Error: Request failed with status code 404
```

But if I do console.error(error.value), it returns null.

Any tips on how to get error.value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [console log event object shows different object properties than it should have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496176/console-log-event-object-shows-different-object-properties-than-it-should-have)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.error(error.value)` outputs the actual value at this moment of time, while `console.error(error)` passes the object  by reference to console and allows to access updated object properties later, this is the use case what ref pattern addresses.

`useFetch` is asynchronous and the result isn't supposed to be instantly available. With composition API, the result is supposed to be accessed as:

```
watch(loading, loadingValue => {
  if (!loadingValue)
    console.error(error.value)
})
```

Alternatively, the hook can be modified to return a promise that could be chained, this is orthogonal to composition API but has its uses to compose hook results with promise control flow:

```
  ...
  const promise = fetch()
  return { status, error, data, loading, promise }
  ...
```

and

```
onMounted(async () => {
  await promise
  console.error(error.value)
})
```

Comment: You're absolutely right! Thanks so much. It makes more sense now!